# ORA-07445: An unexpected error: core dump

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g

We use oracle 10g. We found the following error in a trace file:

```
   *** 2012-05-07 11:50:56.421
   ksedmp: internal or fatal error  
   ORA-07445: An unexpected error: core dump [ACCESS_VIOLATION] [_evaopn2+153] [PC:0x1BBDFA9] [ADDR:0x0] [UNABLE_TO_READ] []
   Current SQL statement for this session:
```

We took a lot of time to find the cause of this problem but we've been unsuccessful. We were using 9i and it did not have this problem. It only showed up after we recently upgraded to 10g.

What is the problem? How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug. See Metalink document 382576.1.

The bug was fixed in Oracle 10.2.0.4, so upgrade to that release (preferably 10.2.0.5).

There are workarounds, but I'm not sure if it's ok to reproduce Metalink documents on this site.

Comment: can we just upgrade to oracle 11g? can we just change some parameter to solve the problem.

Comment: There are workarounds in Oracle support document 382576.1. I'm not going to re-post the content on here. You'll be ok if you upgrade to 11.2